# Trouble with negative binomial regression

Tags: r

I have a data named "doctor" which is concerned with the number of deaths by heart disease in a sample of doctors from different age groups and with different smoking status (smoker/non-smoker).

```
   V2  V3        L4 V5
1   1  32 10.866795  1
2   2 104 10.674706  1
3   3 206 10.261581  1
4   4 186  9.446440  1
5   5 102  8.578665  1
6   1   2  9.841080  2
7   2  12  9.275472  2
8   3  28  8.649974  2
9   4  28  7.857481  2
10  5  31  7.287561  2
```

There are 4 variables: V2 (age groups indexed 1-5), V3 (number of deaths), L4 (log of aggregate years at risk) and V5 (smoking status represented by 1 or 2). I wish to fit a negative binomial regression using the code `nb1=glm.nb(V3~V2+L4+V5,data=doctor)` but get the error message `In glm.nb(V3 ~ V2 + L4 + V5, data = doctor) : alternation limit reached`. What is the problem here?

Comment: can  you provide a [mcve] ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of iterations with [glm.control](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/glm.control)

The following code ran on my system:

```
glm.control(maxit = 25)
nb1=glm.nb(V3~V2+L4+V5, data=doctor)
```

Comment: where did you find the data ... ?

Comment: Will this affect the data in some way?

Comment: No, it still produces the error message